# After upgrading to CartThrob 2.5, cart_items_info no longer working

Tags: cartthrob, checkout

I'm using EE 2.7.2, and just updated to CT2.5. After the update, the cart no longer populates product data inside the `{exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}` tag pair.

For example, if I add an item using `{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart entry_id="{segment_3}" quantity="1" return="cart/index"}`, as I have always done, I'm redirected to the cart, where I see a new line item, the title is blank, and item_price, item_subtotal and cart_subtotal dollar amounts all return $0.00. If I add the same item again, the quantity updates, but the title is still missing as are the dollar amounts; similarly, if I add a different item the cart shows a new line item, but all the same data is missing.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. EE v2.7.3 with CT v2.5. I reverted back to CT 2.4 and works ok again. I also use P&T Matrix where some of the options didn't display (I think this might be when I have them as dynamic options).

Comment: Given the absent support of CartThrob, I decided to jump ship ship and move to Exp:resso. $300 and hours of development, just to have to move to a new store solution. Not stoked.

Comment: They're answering questions here regularly (not this one admittedly) and have free (by appointment) phone support working well now apparently.  Have you tried that?  Also, I am using CT2.5/EE2.7.3 and not experiencing this issue, not that that helps you I realise, but more data is sometimes useful.  I use matrix etc and it's all working ok with CT2.5

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this further and it seems that the dynamic options are nor being picked up. I managed to create a fix for this to mod.cartthrob.php by adding:

```
$option_value = ($item) ? $item->item_options($field_name) : '';
```

after

```
$this->EE->TMPL->tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('option_field', $field_name, $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
```

on line 5021.

I haven't yet seen any problems with this.

Comment: I've noticed that this still hasn't been fixed in the latest version (CT version 2.6). The above fix that I mention above still works if placed in mod.cartthrob.php after line 5046.