# cartthrob 2.5: add_to_cart Tag Not Passing Title Or Price To cart_items_info

Tags: cartthrob

I am using EE2.8.1 with Cartthrob 2.5.

The cartthrob {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form} tag pair is working as intended, and passes the title and price of the specified entry_id without a problem.  However, when attempting to do the same with the single {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart} tag the title and price seem to not be passed and do not show up in the cart when attempting to view with cart_items_info.

I tried the workaround in this [question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/after-upgrading-to-cartthrob-2-5-cart-items-info-no-longer-working), but it appears to be a different issue as the cart_items_info tag is working with the add_to_cart_form in my case, just not with add_to_cart.

For completeness sake, here is the working template code:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form entry_id="90"}

<input type="submit" value="add to cart">

{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

And here is the template code that does not pass the title or price:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart entry_id="90" quantity="1"}
```

Is this a bug?  I suppose I could also try to auto-submit the form version using some javascript, but obviously a native solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that snagging the add_to_cart function from CT 2.4 and replacing the CT 2.5 version seems to work just fine. Haven't found any issues with this so that's my solution for now.

Comment: I've ended up using a different solution involving a channel that acts as a sort of "pre-cart" because of the needs of the site I'm working on, but thank you for your answer and I hope it comes in handy for someone until the folks at CT can patch up the issue in a new release.